# Issue in writing logic into syntactical code

Tags: c++, arrays, string

To check at an index whether it's a consonant or a vowel , and having a bit of a problem with the writing of the logic in syntactical form?

Tried running it but the count variable wasn't incrementing.

```
if (s[i]!= ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') && s[i+1] == ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'))
```

It keeps giving 0 , i.e , the initialised value as the output.

Comment: You can declare a string that contains all vowels and another string that contains consonants and then to use standard C function strchr.

Comment: Explaining the behavior: `char` doesn't overload `operator||`, so instead they both convert to booleans. So `s[i]!= ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')` becomes `s[i]!= (true || true || true || true || true)`, which becomes `s[i]!=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function. For example:

```
bool isvowel( char c ) {
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}
```

Then you can simply say:

```
if ( !isvowel( s[i] )  && isvowel( s[i+1] )  )  {
      // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank You.Definitely Was Of Great Help.But Can You Also Let Me Know If I Somehow Wanted to do it with the If Statement used in my Original Code?I Just Want My Concepts To Get Cleared.Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a separate function that checks whether a given character is a vowel. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

bool is_vowel( char c )
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    return c != '\0' && std::strchr( vowels, std::tolower( ( unsigned char )c ) );
}

int main( void )
{
    std::string s( "Hi" );

    if ( not is_vowel( s[0] ) && is_vowel( s[1] ) ) std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
Hi
```